# How to make Jalapeno Jelly?

Tags: jalapeno, jelly

A friend of mine got into a discussion about how awesome it would be to have really spicy Jelly for a number of things, or atleast just to try the taste.

It didn't seem like there was anything that would specifically make this impossible so I ask:

Is it possible to make Jalapeno jelly, and if so, what would I need to do to make it?

Comment: FWIW, it's really quite good on toast w/ a plate of scrambled eggs...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's [quite a few recipes online](http://www.google.com/search?q=jalapeno+jelly&spell=1).

[This one](http://allrecipes.com//Recipe/jalapeno-jelly/Detail.aspx) seems pretty simple.

It looks like in general, you:

1. Liquify your peppers
2. Cook the result with vinegar
3. Strain it
4. Cook the result with salt and sugar
5. Add some pectin
6. Add some whole jalepenos (probably optional)
7. Transfer to jars

Answer (score 3):

Yep, it's possible! AllRecipes has a highly rated recipe for Jalapeño jelly:
http://allrecipes.com//Recipe/jalapeno-jelly/Detail.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I tried a raspberry jelly with paprika, and that was pretty good. Wouldn't eat it by itself, but it would be good as an inbetween dish to clear the palate, or maybe there is some other use. I'm still thinking of ideas for it.

It seems like a jelly equivalent of chili chocolate.